# XSLT: How can I get the names of all nodes?

Tags: xslt

I'm looking for a stylesheet which prints the name of each node including its value. Getting the value is easy but I don't know how to get the name of each node. Here's the basic template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" />   
    <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:for-each select="/">
         ???
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Could anyone give me a hint?

Thanks,
Robert

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, very short and easy solution :)

Comment: There is a name only for three of the seven node types: elements, attributes and namespace nodes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**This complete transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
 <xsl:variable name="vQ">"</xsl:variable>

 <xsl:template match="*">
     <xsl:value-of select=
       "concat(name(), ' = ', $vQ, ., $vQ, '&#xA;')"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on any XML document, such as this**:

```
<nums>
  <num>01</num>
  <num>02</num>
  <num>03</num>
  <num>04</num>
  <num>05</num>
  <num>06</num>
  <num>07</num>
  <num>08</num>
  <num>09</num>
  <num>10</num>
</nums>
```

**produces exactly the wanted, correct result:**

```
nums = "01020304050607080910"
num = "01"
num = "02"
num = "03"
num = "04"
num = "05"
num = "06"
num = "07"
num = "08"
num = "09"
num = "10"
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't know what you really want, but if I take your requirement literally, it is met by:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//node()">
  <node name="{name()}" value="{string(.)}"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 1):

[Name](http://www.java2s.com/Code/XML/XSLT-stylesheet/Elementnamexslvalueofselectname.htm)(), *"Returns the name of the current node or the first node in the specified node set"*

```
    <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
```

Also,

[local-name()](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_functions.asp) - *"Returns the name of the current node or the first node in the specified node set - without the namespace prefix"*

And I think you want this,

```
 <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="//*">
            <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>=<xsl:apply-templates select="current()/text()"/>
            <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```